# Отладка с sys.stdin в PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

Как можно работать в отладке с sys.stdin в PyCharm? А точнее, как ввести данные?

```
import sys

data = list(map(str, sys.stdin))
```

Проблема в общем состоит в вводе текста с sys.stdin в отладчике PyCharm.

Как с этим работать в отладке?

Comment: Мне нужно отладить получаемый текст, но для этого его сначала надо ввести, именно в этом то по сути то и состоит проблема.

Comment: В этой строке не нужно ничего отлаживать, тут просто получение строк текста в виде отдельных строк. Поставьте точку останова на строках ниже. Кстати, `map` тут не нужен, достаточно просто `data = list(sys.stdin)`, т.к. строки и так имеют тип `str`.