# Как работать в отладке с sys.stdin в PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, отладка, pycharm, stdin

Задача такова: мне нужно понять как отладить программу:

```py
import sys

data = list(map(str, sys.stdin))
...
```

Когда отладчик доходит до `data = list(map(str, sys.stdin))` я должен вводить значения (потоковый ввод), но у меня не получается это сделать. Показывает розовым цветом сообщение

> "Pause the process to use command-line."

**Что мне делать, чтобы отладчик прочел значения из sys.stdin, закончил чтение и пошел дальше отлаживать программу?**

Точка останова не помогает, как было сказано в похожем вопросе: [Отладка с sys.stdin в PyCharm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1249769/452770)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Звучит как вот эта бага в PyCharm - [PY-42488](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42488).

Проблема еще в том что IDE [не умеет обрабатывать](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24953) <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> поэтому в любом случае не получится прервать чтение STDIN.

В качестве альтернативы можно создать файл с тем что вы собираетесь отправлять на STDIN и передать его в Run Configuration в поле "Redirect input from"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]